# Return two different models in the same queryset in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Let's use these 2 simple models for example. A product can have multiple images.

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=10000)

class Image(models.Model):
    image=models.ImageField(null=True)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='related_product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In my viewset, in get_queryset(), I am fetching list of all the products, based on some keyword filter on the product's name and all their images, with

```
queryset = Product.objects.select_related('image').filter(name__contains="Fanta").all()
```

To the client, I want to return:

1. JSON, a table, list of all the products (product_id, product_name, product_description) and,
2. Another JSON, another separate table of all the images of all the products. (image_id, image, product_id)

One way to do this is to make a combined Serializer, which will give me the fields (image_id, image, product_id, product_name, product_description)
But I don't want this, since for every image, the product_description will be repeated, and since that one can be quite large, 10.000 characters, I want to find a more optimal way. I want to get the product_description as well, but only once, there is no need to repeat it in every row, for every image of that product.

Another way to do this is to make two separate viewsets, each one with its own get_queryset(). But for the product model, I will have to filter the product_names by keyword, and in the other viewset, to get the images, I have to filter again by product_names, to get the relevant images. Since filtering names is obviously very slow, I don't want to do it twice unnecessarily.

I also looked into Django's queryset caching, but I don't understand how can I use it in my scenario.

A third approach I saw on stackoverflow, but doesn't work for me, is with

```
from itertools import chain
queryset1 = Product.objects.select_related('image').filter(name__contains="Fanta").all()
queryset2 = #somehow I slice from queryset1, and extract only the products
queryset3 = #somehow I slice from queryset1, and extract only the images
return chain( queryset2,queryset3)
```

This doesn't work and I don't know why.
Just this line, returning queryset2, or just returning queryset3 alone, works perfectly

```
return queryset2
```

I have never used that "from itertools import chain", so maybe I am making some other mistakes I am not aware in the process.

So, as the question's title asks, how do I return two querysets from two different models, in a single viewset and single get_queryset() ? Without having a combined serializer, and repeating the product_description, in every row for every image.

Comment: [dublicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65061179/get-products-and-images-from-two-django-models-by-filtering-the-product-name-an/65075219)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GET products and images from two Django models, by filtering the product name and accessing the database only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65061179/get-products-and-images-from-two-django-models-by-filtering-the-product-name-an)